# Uniformly convex Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a uniformly convex Banach space. Let $A$ and $B$ be two nonempty closed convex subsets of $X$. Let

$$A_0=\{x \in A: \Vert x-y \Vert= \mbox{dist}(A,B) \thinspace \mbox{for some } \thinspace y \in B \},$$

$$B_0=\{y \in B: \Vert x-y \Vert =\mbox{dist}(A,B) \thinspace \mbox{for some } \thinspace x \in A\}.$$

Here $\mbox{dist}(A,B)=\inf \{\Vert x-y \Vert: x \in A, y \in B\}$. It is given that $A_0$ is nonempty and suppose that

$$\Vert x_1-y_1 \Vert =\mbox{dist}(A,B) \quad \mbox{and} \quad \Vert x_2-y_2 \Vert = \mbox{dist}(A,B),$$

where $x_1,x_2 \in A$ and $y_1,y_2 \in B$.

I want to prove that

$$\Vert x_1-x_2 \Vert=\Vert y_1-y_2 \Vert.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By uniform convexity $\|(x_1-y_1) - (x_2-y_2)\|=0$ (otherwise $\|(x_1+x_2)/2 - (y_1+y_2)/2 \|< dist(A,B)$ - a contradiction).
Then by triangly inequality
$$
\|x_1-x_2 \| = \|x_1-x_2 -(y_1-y_2) + y_1-y_2\| \le 0 + \|y_1-y_2\|.
$$
Similarly, $\|y_1-y_2\|\le \|x_1-x_2\|$ can be obtained.

Comment: How are we getting a contradiction. If we assume that $\Vert (x_1-y_1)-(x_2-y_2) \Vert >0$. Then by Uniform convexity $\Big\Vert \frac{x_1-y_1+x_2-y_2}{2} \Big\Vert  < \mbox{dist}(A,B)$. How will this be a contadiction?

Comment: By convexity $(x_1+x_2)/2\in A$ and $(y_1+y_2)/2\in B$. So $dist(A,B)\le \|(x_1+x_2)/2-(y_1-y_2)/2\| < dist(A,B)$, which is impossible